# Forward depending on domain name

Tags: web

I have to domain names, and one hosting server. How do I forward a visit if it comes from domain name A (www.A.com) to index_A.html and if it comes from domain name B (www.B.com) to www.index_B.html?

Thank you!
Kasper

Answer (score 1):

Do the directories for the two need to be the same? Can you use .htaccess to forward?

- Yes, Yes

Use htaccess to forward visits to index_{a,b}.html

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?somedomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://somedomain.com/index_b.html [L]
```

- No, Yes

Change the directories for each in your HTTPd configuration.

- Yes, No

You could use PHP or some other web language to determine the incoming domain and forward accordingly (e.g. index.php -> index_a.html or index_b.html).

Comment: I am trying to get it done with .htaccess, but it doesn't work. I have only one .htaccess file as I have only one server. What should I put in the code? Something like if it comes from this URL forward it to that one...

Comment: Edited/Added htaccess relevant to your issue.